# Parameterized Group and Toggel Visibility in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

i Have Report where i have 5 Groups Every Group is Depend on its upper group and display can be toggled by this report Item.Like Below Image
[image]

Now i have Parameter as User Role if i Pass NM then All Group has to Show. if i pass RM then start Visibility from RM. the Problem is if i Pass RM then only Headers are Showing not the Data becasue its Toggle Visibility is Depend on NM which is now not visible.

Please Reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please don't waste time because Toggle visibility can not be set dynamically.

Please create different report for different login.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to change your visibility expression for the other groups so that instead of just having NM showing the visibility, it should have a nested iif for RM.  For instance,

=iif(Parameters!Value="NM",1,iif(Parameters!Value="RM",1,0))

If the issue is your group visibility and not row visibility then you can change the visibility for the NM group to actually be a row visibility setting versus a group visibility setting because NM is a parent group it may hide it by default. Then you can change your grouping expression to also reflect that it should not group on NM if it has RM parameter.

Comment: There are two places for a row to set visibility, Group Level and Row Level.  I recommend trying to set the visibility on the Row Level rather than the Group Level if you want the inner group to show.

Comment: You can also change it so if you are grouping on the NM to be the same value for every RM value and this way they group all together.